# Meteor on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012, meteor

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2012 as an IDE for Meteor.

I want to change behaviour of VS2012 for building and publishing. So that there is nothing for VS to build, when I will click build button, I want VS2012 to just run meteor command inside a ruby command window.

And when I will click publish button, I want VS2012 to deploy my application to (appname).meteor.com

For both cases I will need to set paths. I am trying to modify project file but so far no luck...

Any help appriciated.

Comment: You might be better off investigating creating a webmatrix extension instead of trying to "fix" Visual Studio to work with meteor. http://extensions.webmatrix.com/doc/howcreatewmxextensions.html Webmatrix seems to be Microsoft's prefer way of bundling anything that isn't in the Visual Studio supported languages clique.

Comment: I will try what you said.